# What glob pattern to use for files inside a folder AND sub-folders?

Tags: javascript, glob, minimatch

I'm trying to run a npm task to lint against certain JS files.

Given the following list files:

```
/root.js                            // should be excluded
/js-src/lib/test.js                 // should be excluded
/js-src/lib/anotherTst.js           // should be excluded
/js-src/utilities/anotherModule.js  // should be included
/js-src/modules/myModule.js         // should be included
/js-src/common.js                   // should be included
```

The following pattern will work for all sub-folders excluding 'lib': `./js-src/!(lib)/**/*.js`. However, common.js is ignored as is visible here on [globtester](http://www.globtester.com/#p=eJzTzyrWLS5K1lfUyMlM0tTX0tLX0ssqBgBLagZB&r=eJyNy8EJgDAMheFVpHfNAtUNvLlArQUjjYEmFdxeEVQ8KF7f%2B3474FL46ERqYxpIzFpNYmGfG%2Fv8JikleYjYgwb5w9zMOobUvWBy6se7yIoRFYOcXctDjuFPSocUoPWjublnIp4vtAH7%2F1sX&)

What should the mini match/globbing pattern be in order for this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `/**/!(lib)/*.js` using [globster.xyz](https://globster.xyz/?q=%2F**%2F!(lib)%2F*.js&f=%2Froot.js%2C%2Fjs-src%2Flib%2Ftest.js%2C%2Fjs-src%2Flib%2FanotherTst.js%2C%2Fjs-src%2Futilities%2FanotherModule.js%2C%2Fjs-src%2Fmodules%2FmyModule.js%2C%2Fjs-src%2Fcommon.js)